# Replace list into list of list

Tags: scheme, racket

How can I build a function that receives a list and builds 2 lists that on the first one are all the even numbers and on the other one are all the odd numbers?

For the input:  `(fun '(1 2 3 4 5 6))`
the output will be: `((2 4 6) (1 3 5))`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a built-in for that, simply use [partition](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Flist..rkt%29._partition%29%29) and provide the right predicate. The rest of the code is just for capturing the returned values and building the output list:

```
(define (my-partition lst)
  (let-values ([(evens odds) (partition even? lst)])
    (list evens odds)))
```

For example:

```
(my-partition '(1 2 3 4 5 6))
=> '((2 4 6) (1 3 5))
```